# SQL - Update top n records for each value in column a where n = count of column b

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table with the following columns and sample values:

```
    [test]
    ID | Sample | Org | EmployeeNumber
    1             100      6513241
    2             200      3216542
    3             300      5649841
    4             100      9879871
    5             200      6546548
    6             100      1116594
```

My example count query based on [test] returns these sample values grouped by Org:

```
    Org | Count of EmployeeNumber
    100             3
    200             2
    300             1
```

My question is can I use this count to update test.Sample to 'x' for the top 3 records of Org 100, the top 2 records of Org 200, and the top 1 record of Org 300? It does not matter which records are updated, as long as the number of records updated for the Org = the count of EmployeeNumber.

I realize that I could just update all records in this example but I have 175 Orgs and 900,000 records and my real count query includes an iif that only returns a partial count based on other columns.

The db that I am taking over uses a recordset and loop to update. I am trying to write this in one SQL update statement. I have tried several variations of nested select statements but can't quite figure it out. Any help would save my brain from exploding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that `id` is the unique ID of the row, you could use a correlated subquery to select the count of row IDs of the rows sharing the current organization, that are less than or equal to the current row ID and check, that this count is less than or equal to the number of records from that organization you want to designate.

For example to mark 3 records of the organization 100 you could use:

```
UPDATE test
       SET sample = 'x'
       WHERE org = 100
             AND (SELECT count(*)
                         FROM test t
                         WHERE t.org = test.org
                               AND t.id <= test.id) <= 3;
```

And analog for the other cases.

(Disclaimer: I don't have access to Access (ha, ha, pun), so I could not test it. But I guess it's basic enough, to work in almost every DBMS, also in Access.)